# Intellij IDEA on Mac OS: open file at a line number from terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, intellij-idea, terminal

I can open a file from terminal using this command:

`/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS/idea <absolute-path-to-file>`

But, when I pass the line number to it, it doesn't work:

`/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS/idea <absolute-path-to-file> --line 50`

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. `--line 50` should go before the file name or it doesn't work and it doesn't give any error message!